# Performing computations with values of two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas data frames.

**DataFrame 1**

```
Index_Col    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5

Row1         0.64   0.89   0.76   0.22   1.34

Row2         0.54   0.56   0.82   0.46   0.23

and so on.
```

DataFrame 2 has Thresholds for each of the columns in dataframe1 as a range.

**DataFrame 2**

```
Column_Name    Group    Min     Max

col1           G1        0.5    1

col2           G1        0.1    2

col3           G2        0.3    0.9

col4           G1        0.3    1

col5           G2        0.7    2

and so on
```

I am trying to compute `value = ((value - Min)/(Max - Min))*100` for every value in every column of DataFrame1. For example, the value of Row1 of Col1 will be 
`((0.64-0.5)/(1-0.5))*100`.

I tried converting everything to lists and compute using multiple for loops. But I would like to know if there's any simpler method.

Comment: provide some code to recreate your example

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Is it just the same shape as `df1`, just with your computation in place of the values? Things like this change how to implement a solution.

Comment: @ALollz Yes the output structure should be the same as DataFrame1 but with computations

Comment: @BlueMoon
import pandas as pd
DataFrame1 = [['Index_Col', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'], ['Row1', '0.64', '0.89', '0.76', '0.22', '1.34'], ['Row2', '0.54', '0.56', '0.82', '0.46', '0.23']]
DataFrame2 = [['Column_Name', 'Group', 'Min', 'Max'], ['col1', 'G1', '0.5', '1'],            ['col2', 'G1', '0.1','2'], ['col3', 'G2', '0.3', '0.9'], ['col4', 'G1', '0.3', '1'],          ['col5', 'G2',  '0.7', '2']]
DataFrame1 = pd.DataFrame(DataFrame1)
DataFrame1.reset_index(drop=True)
DataFrame2 = pd.DataFrame(DataFrame2)
DataFrame2.reset_index(drop=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import io


# SAmple Data
df1 = pd.read_table(io.StringIO("""
Index_Col    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
Row1         0.64   0.89   0.76   0.22   1.34
Row2         0.54   0.56   0.82   0.46   0.23
"""),delim_whitespace=True)


df2 = pd.read_table(io.StringIO("""
Column_Name    Group    Min     Max
col1           G1        0.5    1
col2           G1        0.1    2
col3           G2        0.3    0.9
col4           G1        0.3    1
col5           G2        0.7    2
"""), delim_whitespace=True)

# Melt the wide data frame so that each cell is a row
df1m = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=["Index_Col"], var_name="Col")

# Lowercase the column name to match with df2
df1m['Column_Name']  = df1m['Col'].str.lower()

# Join the melted dataframe with the thresholds in df2
df1mj = df1m.merge(df2, left_on="Column_Name", right_on="Column_Name")

# Calculate
df1mj['new_value'] = ((df1mj['value'] - df1mj['Min'])/(df1mj['Max'] - df1mj['Min']))*100

# Use pivot to reassemble the wide dataframe
result = df1mj.pivot(index = "Index_Col", columns="Col", values="new_value")
```

Result:

```
Col        Col1       Col2       Col3       Col4       Col5
Index_Col                                                  
Row1       28.0  41.578947  76.666667 -11.428571  49.230769
Row2        8.0  24.210526  86.666667  22.857143 -36.153846
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.